# How can I handle this Prisma error in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, next.js, prisma

I have a register API that I wrote using Next.js, Prisma, Zod and TypeScript.

I can manually register as many users as I want. There is no problem. As you can imagine, it can be very difficult to test manually. So I wrote a Node.js script for this, but I'm running into a problem.

First of all, let me write the operations I do in order:

i) I create random users using Faker.js and save them in `users.json` file.

```
import fs from "fs";
import { faker } from "@faker-js/faker";

const generateUser = () => {

  // Create an array to store the users
  const users = [];

  // Create a set to store the used emails
  const usedEmails = new Set();
  // Generate 100 random users
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // Generate a random username
    let username = faker.name.firstName();

    // Check if the username has been used before
    while (usedEmails.has(username)) {
      console.log(
        `Warning: ${email} has already been used, new e-mail is being created.`
      );
      username = faker.name.firstName();
    }

    // Generate a random email
    const email = faker.internet.email();

    // Check if the email has been used before
    if (usedEmails.has(email)) {
      console.log(
        `Warning: ${email} has already been used, new e-mail is being created.`
      );
      email = faker.internet.email();
    }

    // Generate a random password
    const password = faker.internet.password();

    // Check if the username is at least 5 characters long
    while (username.length < 5) {
      username = faker.name.firstName();
    }

    // Create a user object
    const user = {
      username,
      email,
      password,
    };

    // Log the user creation
    console.log(`User has been created: ${i}`);

    // Add the user to the users array
    users.push(user);
  }
  // Log the duplicated emails
  console.log("Duplicated e-mails:", usedEmails);

  // Convert the users array to JSON
  const jsonUsers = JSON.stringify(users);

  // Write the users to the users.json file
  fs.writeFile("users.json", jsonUsers, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Users has been saved to users.json");
  });
};

// Generate the users
generateUser();
```

ii) I send each user in the `users.json` file to the register API via a script with the POST method.

```
import users from "./users.json" assert { type: "json" };
import axios from "axios";

export const registerUsers = async (users) => {
  const failedEmails = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    const user = users[i];

    const data = {
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email.trim(),
      password: user.password,
    };

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register",
        data
      );
      console.log(`User ${i} registered:`, response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        `There is an error while trying to register ${i} (${user.email})`,
        error.response.data
      );
      if (error.response.data.errors.includes("This e-mail is already taken.")) {
        failedEmails.push(user.email);
      }
    }

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1));
  }

  console.log("All users have been registered!");
  console.log(`Failed e-mails (${failedEmails.length}): ${failedEmails.join(", ")}`);
};

registerUsers(users);
```

This is exactly where the problem starts. There are no duplicated emails in the `users.json` file, but when I run the register script, at least a few of the users return errors from the server every time.

My register API code:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import crypto from "crypto";
import { z } from "zod";
import { hashPassword } from "@/utils/utils";
import { registerResponse, registerRequestSchema } from "@/utils/zodSchemas";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();
type ResponseType = z.infer<typeof registerResponse>;

export default async function handleRegister(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<ResponseType>,
) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return res.status(405).json({ success: false, errors: ["Method not allowed"] });
  }

  const parsed = await registerRequestSchema.safeParseAsync(req.body);

  if (!parsed.success) {
    const errorMap = parsed.error.flatten().fieldErrors;
    const errorMessages = Object.values(errorMap).flatMap(
      (errors) => errors ?? [],
    );

    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, errors: errorMessages });
  }

  const { username, email, password } = parsed.data;

  const { salt, hash } = hashPassword(
    password,
    crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex"),
  );

  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        username,
        email,
        hash,
        salt,
      },
    });

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email,
      message: "Sucess!",
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
      if (err.code === "P2002") {
        return res.status(400).json({
          success: false,
          errors: ["This e-mail is already taken."],
        });
      }
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      return res
        .status(500)
        .json({ success: false, errors: ["Internal Server Error"] });
    }
  }
}
```

To summarize;

(i) I create random users (I check and no two e-mails are the same),

(ii) I send these users to the register API and,

(iii) although no two e-mails are the same, at least 2-3 users do not register and the error "This e-mail is already taken" is returned.

Whatever I did, I couldn't solve the problem. I would be very grateful if you could help me. Thanks in advance.

I even increased the timeout time of requests to the API to 5 seconds, but I still got the same error. I tried many ways but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: Have you tried checking if user is really in the database or not? Also, are you sure that P2002 can only be cause by duplicates? It would be helpful to see full error message in err.

Comment: Please add the error too